# Calculating a percentage, is there a more optimised way?

Tags: javascript

```
var q3a1 = parseInt(valueOne); //get variables
var q3a2 = parseInt(valueTwo);
var q3a3 = parseInt(valueThree);

var totalAmountThree = Math.ceil((q3a1+q3a2+q3a3) / 100)*100; //round to nearest 100

var percentOnec = ((q3a1 / totalAmountThree) * 100); //calculate percentage
var percentTwoc = ((q3a2 / totalAmountThree) * 100);
var percentThreec = ((q3a3 / totalAmountThree) * 100);

alert("1: "+percentOnec);
alert("2: "+percentTwoc);
alert("3: "+percentThreec);
```

Is there a better way for me to be calculating a percentage?

(Fiddle with me: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/Sez3Q/)

Comment: Why the rounding to the nearest 100? This doesn't seem to make sense, but maybe I am missing something...

Comment: It was originally outputting to 98 or 99% :/

Comment: Rounding to 100's doesn't make sense to me either. Since all of your values are integers from the start, you will get floating point results only when counting percentages. But if you round, your percentages will never sum up to 100%. Or so I believe...

Comment: when you say outputting to 98 or 99%, what do you really mean? it would be better to do the rounding off *after* the final calculation, in my opinion. and make it significant to so many decimal places.

Comment: ok, could anyone provide me with the `correct` code for calculating percentages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* optimize this by calculating the factor, needed to scale to percentage directly:

```
S = A+B+C
p(x)=100*x / S
```

so the 'factor' is `100/(A+B+C)`:

```
var total = a+b+c;
var scale = 100/total;

function pct(x) { return x*scale; }
```

And it can be generalized, of course, to work with an array of input values etc...

```
function toPctFn( values ) {
   var sum = 0;
   for( var i = 0; i != values.length; ++i ) { sum = sum + values[i]; }
   var scale = 100/sum;
   return function( x ){ 
     return x*scale;
   };
}

var inputs=[1,2,40,44,23];
var toPct=toPctFn(inputs);

for( var i = 0; i != inputs.length; ++i ) { 
   alert(""+i+": "+toPct(inputs[i])) ;
}
```

(see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtofl/b8BXL/))

Also, it's quite important to postpone rounding to the displaying code.  This way you don't introduce unnecessary errors in the calculation.

Comment: cool, how (with my current code) can I get the correct percentages. Your code (although nice), is overkill and I can't really use the Array idea either :'( (+1 to you)

Answer (score 1):

you're introducing rounding off errors, first on the line using Math.ceil(). If there's no reason to round off to the nearest hundred first, it's better to leave it out. It's possible to have a significant (depending on what you're calculating) disparity between the 'real' value and your calculation.